# How to parse number with points and commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, decimal, precision

I recieve an string like;

**1.234.567,89**

I want **1234567.89**

Comma is decimal delimiter.Point is thousands, and millions delimiter

I want to treat as a number.

I try replaces, but only works with first ".". And parseFloat.
Also I try some regex that found here,but doesn't work for me

I want this;

```
    var numberAsString= '1.234.567,89';
    //Step to clean string and conver to a number to compare (numberAsString => numberCleaned)
    if (numberCleaned> 1000000) {alert("greater than 1 million");}
```

Any Idea?
(Sorry if its a newbie question, but I dont found any solution in hours...)

Comment: Remove all the `.` characters, replace `,` with `.`, and then call `parseFloat()`.

Comment: While asking a question post all the code attempts that you have made. Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `replace` with `g`

```js
const val = '1.234.567,89'.replace(/\./gi, '').replace(/,/, '.');
console.log(val)
console.log(typeof parseFloat(val))
```

Comment: It works perfect!! I chose you as solution! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this should work for the current scenario.
1st remove the dots then replace the comma with dot.

```js
let number = "1.234.567,89";

function parseNum(num){
    return num.replace(/\./g, '').replace(",", ".")
}


console.log(parseNum(number));
```

Comment: or `Number.parseFloat('1.234.567,89'.split('.').join('').replace(',','.'))` but yours is nicer :D

Comment: @Argee well there are obviously a lot of methods to achieve it but the better solution will be easy to understand and re implement.

Comment: Also try this soloution, and works fine, nice for getting more ideas!